# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Website.Model.ModelName>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, many-to-many

I am trying to get checkbox value for my Post edit page from a many-to-many database table. but I receive error,

> ***CS0029:*** Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Website.Model.ModelName>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

`Model`:

```cs
public class PostModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public List<TagModel> Tags { get; set; }

    // Many To Many
    public List<PostTagModel> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class TagModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public List<PostModel> Posts { get; set; }

    // Posts Many to Many
    public List<PostTagModel> PostTags { get; set; }
}
```

`ViewModel`:

```cs
public class EditPostViewModel
{
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public List<int>? TagId { get; set; }

    public List<TagModel>? TagList { get; set; }
}
```

`Controller`:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
{
    // Id Check
    var post = await _postInterface.GetByIdAsync(id);

    // Check
    if (post == null)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }

    var postVM = new EditPostViewModel
    {
        Title = post.Title,
        Description = post.Description,
        TagId = post.Tags, // Where I receive error

        // List
        TagList = await _context.Tags.ToListAsync()
    };

    return View(postVM);
}
```

**What I tried**

I tried using many different variables for `TagId` but to no luck. Here is an example example:

```cs
var selectedTags = await _context.Posts.Select(p => p.Tags).SingleAsync();

var postVM = new EditPostViewModel
{    
    TagId = selectedTags, // Gives same or nearly similar errors
};
```

Comment: Can you share structure of `TagModel` class?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I have updated `TagModel`

Comment: FYI, you don't need the property with `List<PostTagModel>` for both `PostModel` and `TagModel`. AFAIK, for many-to-many relationship, when both entities have the property with `List<>` type for the reference entity, it will automatically create the associate table (for Code-First model); and fetch the related data into the navigation property. You don't need to create the associate entity like `PostTagModel` and the property with associate entity for associate table.

Answer (score 0):

`Tags` property of `PostModel` class is of type `List<TagModel>` and you are trying to assign it to `TagIds` which is of type `List<int>?`.

To fix this issue, you have to get all Ids of `Tag` and assign it to `TagIds`.

```
var postVM = new EditPostViewModel
{
    Title = post.Title,
    Description = post.Description,
    TagId = post.Tags.Select(x => x.Id).ToList(), 
                   //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This will project a new list of ids. 
    TagList = await _context.Tags.ToListAsync()
};
```

Comment: Gives error ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source'). When debugged, `post.Tags` shows null

Comment: That means there is no tags present in the given `post` variable. You should check reason why `Post.Tags` is coming as a null.

This is not relevant to the error that you attached in the question

Comment: Reason why your `Tags` is null as you need to eager loading to load the related `Tag` entities for `post`. So when you get the selected post, it should be: `post = await _context.Posts.Include(p => p.Tags).SingleAsync(x => x.Id == id);`

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear enough: you have type mismatch. You can solve this by using:

```cs
TagId = post.Tags?.Select(t => t.Id).ToList(),
```

But, seems like the problem is starting in the `GetByIdAsync()` method. From some reason the `Tags` property doesn't initialized. Therefore, it is necessary to use the  [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) to prevent applying the `Select()` when the `Tags` property evaluates to `null`.

Also, the second option is to perform initializing the `Tags` property when creating an instance of the `PostModel`:

```cs
public List<TagModel> Tags { get; set; } = new List<TagModel>();
```